# Adding a scrollbar inside the table body

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add both vertical and horizontal scrollbars into my table, however, I tried a lot of tutorials from the internet, but none of those seem to work for me.

How can I add Both vertical and horizontal scrollbars using CSS?

```html
<div class="tablecontainer">
  <div class="table" >
    <table cellspacing='0'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Tutor Name </th>
          <th>Tutor NRIC</th>
          <th>Tutor ID</th>
          <th>Tutor Email</th>
          <th>Tutor qualification</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Jane</td> 
          <td>1234567</td>
          <td>Jane@gmail.com</td>
          <td>Diploma</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: An easier way than what? You haven't shared what you have tried

Comment: Try this  class to table 
.styleClass{
overflow-x: visible|hidden|scroll|auto|initial|inherit;
overflow-y: visible|hidden|scroll|auto|initial|inherit;
}

Comment: Can you please post the code? A skeleton is fine.

Comment: http://codepen.io/ginginhui/pen/Qypyby , i need to have both vertical and horizontal scrollbar with fixed header . can you guys help me with that ?

Answer (score 1):

The most simplest solution to add both horizontal and vertical scrollbar will be,

Add the class `table` to your table where you want to show the scrollbars, and include following in the CSS part(or external stylesheet)

```
.table {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-x : scroll;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Optionally, you may also specify `height` and `width` manually.

I've created [CodePen](http://codepen.io/snazzysanoj/pen/pgegjE) using your code with both scrollbars.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: hey, thanks a lot , but it doesnt come out anything :(

Comment: Can you please post a [CodePen](http://codepen.io), so I can take a look at code? Simple skeleton of the table without actual content will be fine

Comment: I've added the working code to my answer. Please mark my answer as accepted, if it worked for you :)

Comment: Can you create a [CodePen](http://codepen.io), so that I can take a look at the code?

Comment: omg , thank you so much , but however, i need the header to be fixed , do you think u can help me with that ?
thank you so much in advance

Comment: updated..Mark my answer as accepted if it worked for you. :)

Comment: yup , okay , marked . :)  can you help me to adjust the scroll into the tbody , because i need the header to be fix , thank you !!! i really helped me a lot ^^

Comment: Yes, of course... You can hire me on [Freelancer.com](https://www.freelancer.com/u/snazzysanoj.html), and I'll be happy to help you out... :)

Comment: haha , i am afraid i cant do that, i am just a student with no job :(

Answer (score 0):

For vertical scrolling, make sure you have the nowrap attribute in your css to prevent your table from wrapping upon resize.

```
    td {
       white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

For horizontal scaling, make sure you set overflow to "scroll" in your css along with a height attribute for your table's content.

```
    .scrollContent {
        height: 170px
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
```

Here is a jsfiddle of a modified version of the table at http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html to include vertical scrolling: https://jsfiddle.net/yv193jmy/

Answer (score -1):

What have you tried?
The most simple is to add

```
.table {
  overflow : scroll;
}
```

to your CSS

Comment: hey, yup , i tried , but it cant work too :( , there is no scroll bar at all :(